# How do I Center the Storefront Menu?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, storefront

To replicate my problem go to the storefront demo page here: https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/ and delete the node `<ul id="site-header-cart" class="site-header-cart menu"></ul>` that contains the cart box (to the right of the menu) so that the main menu is by itself.

Here is where I am stuck, I can't figure out how to center the menu.

I have tried a lot of different combinations but I just can't understand what is going on with the WooCommerce/storefront css. It makes no sense to me.

Here is what is working for me...

```
.woocommerce-active .site-header .main-navigation {
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-primary-menu {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But I have no idea why it only works with `display: table`. I tried using flexbox but no flexbox rules seem to work anywhere! It's so confusing to do something so simple.

Comment: can you add the html code, or add code snippets

Comment: Hi adam, my site is on my local host but it is idential to the demo which I linked to in my post above, an out of the box storefront theme, only difference being that I have removed the cart element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking their stylistic choices. You can try this instead:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .woocommerce-active .site-header .main-navigation {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

It works by removing the limited width, and the margin that bumped the "cart" over a bit more. Now that it's full width, you can just center the text:

[image: Preview]

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly. Totally overthinking it. Thank you for the help!